# What are the problems with using Jax-RS instead of Cloud Endpoints on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jax-rs, integration-testing, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm developing a java web project on Google App Engine/Datastore as a mobile app backend.

The requirement is to only use services available for free for low usage in Google Cloud so that I can get started cheaply and (theoretically) have to do much less work to scale up to handle more users.

I am a JavaEE developer and am considering using Jax-RS inside Google App Engine instead of Google Cloud Endpoints.

Having read [JAX-RS services in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254232/jax-rs-services-in-google-app-engine) and some other answers, I am interested in answers to the following questions, **especially in 2018 as most answers are very old**:

- What would I give up by using Jax-RS instead of Cloud Endpoints in terms of:

  - Are Cloud Endpoints easier to use when integrated with Google's auth sdk?
  - Would I be giving up anything in terms of logging and metrics?
  - Is testing with Arquillian more difficult when I combine App Engine runtime with Jax-RS for any reason?
  - Would the Jax-RS servlet require custom plumbing to enable SSL?
  - Anything I haven't thought of...

To me, the obvious advantages of Jax-RS are it's ease of development (Cloud Endpoints appears to require more boilerplate) and the fact that I am already very familiar with it.

Experienced advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use JAX-RS, but you lose some of Cloud Endpoints features like:

- [Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users)
- [Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/monitoring-your-api) -- Though each request will get the normal [Stackdriver trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/)
- Arquillian should work with either.
- SSL should be available either way. (Note it terminates at our load balancer not the app)

The key feature you loose by using Jax-RS instead of Cloud Endpoints is [Service Control](https://cloud.google.com/service-control/overview).